# How should I approach a 300 classes classification machine learning problem?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to make a Multi-Class classification application, but my dataset has 300 classes, is it possible to train my model with all these classes with a normal PC?

Comment: how many samples and variables do you want? this question is way too general!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it is. You can even train imagenet with 1000 categories or more, if you have enough time! ;)

You just have to think about which loss function you want (categorical crossentropy, sparse categorical crossentropy or even binary if you want to penalize each output node independently), apart from that there's not really much difference between 10, 100 or a 1000 classes.

Of course you have to increase your model size to account for more classes, so RAM may be an issue, but then you can always decrease batch size. If you are using images and convnets and your model is still too large, try to downsample the images, use pooling layers or larger strides.

If your computer is too old and slow, you can also try Google Colab which offers free GPU and even TPU online!

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to answer this question. The training time of your model depends on a number of factors. It might be best to train your model for a certain amount of hours and evaluate the performance. You could make use of fitting a learning curve, which could provide an esitmation of how many data points your require for training to achieve a certain performance. After that you could link the required amount of data points to computation time.

Here is an article provides an algorithm for fitting a learning curve: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3307431/.